# Multiple form submit upon last form PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I am working on a web application using PHP and sql on localhost using wamp server.

I have a requirement to make multiple forms Like personal details, Physical detail medical detail and religion detail with save button for each form in each page of a form. For these forms I designed database tables separately, like personal detail , medical, religion and users details have separate database tables with primary key and a foreign key of User Id from user table to distinguish records specific to each user.

1. My problem now is what approach will I use to submit all forms with
   single button? `Before submitting my application checks whether all required fields are filled or not if filledthen it would submit all pre filled forms.`
2. Second question is when user submits all forms with single click
   where is data is to be stored ?

Comment: What have you tried, and what is your goal?

Comment: i developed forms in different pages .
i have 30 forms in my web app, i want to facilitate user to fill forms one by one when he wants to be available to filling forms example today user only fill one form for Personal detail and save , tomorrows morning he cam up and fill next 4 forms and save it , and so on when he will complete all forms at last form he will able to submit all filled forms , so how could i achieve this

Comment: Your question is not totally related to programming and very opinion based. Anyway, I suggest that you design your form into multiple pages rather than 1 page with multiple forms. When users want to go next page, you validate and submit data for that page only. For the second question, it is depended on how you want to use the data users submit, without details, it's hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you could setup a front-end and back-end form data validation before insert it into database.
For the second question, it is not a problem to design database tables separately, you could just using multiple query to save all the required data on each table.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.

i have 30 forms in my web app, i want to facilitate user to fill forms one by one when he wants to be available to filling forms example today user only fill one form for Personal detail and save , tomorrows morning he cam up and fill next 4 forms and save it , and so on when he will complete all forms at last form he will able to submit all filled forms , so how could i achieve this

Comment: From a design perspective, I think 30 forms is a bit much for a user to fill up simultaneously, so I agree with your decision to split it into few form, you could make a temporary table to store uncompleted user-submitted form data

Comment: Then after user has completed the whole forms, you could transfer each uncompleted user data into the main table and clear the user temporary data on the temporary table

Comment: Hasta Dhana , Thanks for your kindness , i have one more question how i will know that user completed all forms?

Comment: From my approach, store all the form ids, then check whether user temporary data has record of all that form ids, I would prefer to do it on each submitted form.